# How to calculate the number of times a route was travelled using SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to determine how many times a certain route was travelled per vehicle on given a certain date range, but the GPS management software built on top of the database doesn't have this functionality.

The database contains several tables that store GPS, route, and location data.  A route is made up of several locations and a sequence number.  A location is a set of upper and lower bound latitudinal/longitudinal values attached to a name.  A vehicle uploads its GPS location data several times a minute to the server, which updates the GPS table.

eg.  A certain route "FOO" may consist of locations "Warehouse", "School", "Stadium" and "Park" in order.  "BAR" is essentially the same route, but in reverse (locations may be found on several different routes).

A simple select returns this type of information from the GPS data table (vehicle id, location, datetime):

```
34  Warehouse  2011-03-26 18:17:50.000
34  Warehouse  2011-03-26 18:18:30.000
34  Warehouse  2011-03-26 18:19:05.000
34  School     2011-03-26 18:21:34.000
34  School     2011-03-26 18:21:59.000
34  School     2011-03-26 18:22:42.000
34  School     2011-03-26 18:23:55.000
34  Stadium    2011-03-26 18:24:20.000
34  Stadium    2011-03-26 18:24:47.000
34  Park       2011-03-26 18:25:30.000
34  Park       2011-03-26 18:26:50.000
34  Warehouse  2011-03-26 18:28:50.000
```

etc.

It's clear from manual inspection that vehicle 34 travelled route "FOO" at least once that day.  How can I use SQL to determine the total number times that route was travelled on that day, per vehicle?

I get the feeling I'm going to have to use some sort of control-break structure but I'm hoping there's an easier way.  This is the SQL used to retrieve the info from the GPS table.

```
SELECT
    v.VehicleID,
    ml.LocationName
    gps.Time,
FROM dbo.Routes r 
INNER JOIN dbo.RoutePoints rp 
        ON r.RouteId = rp.RouteId
INNER JOIN dbo.MapLocations ml
        ON rp.LocationId = ml.LocationId
INNER JOIN dbo.GPSData gps 
        ON ml.LowerRightLatitude  < gps.Latitude  AND ml.UpperLeftLatitude  > gps.Latitude
        AND ml.UpperLeftLongitude < gps.Longitude AND ml.LowerRightLongitude > gps.Longitude
INNER JOIN dbo.Vehicles v 
        ON gps.VehicleID = v.VehicleID 
WHERE   r.Desc = @routename
AND gps.Time BETWEEN @startTime AND @endTime
ORDER BY v.VehicleId, gps.Time
```

EDIT:
Backtracking is not considered part of the same route. *Warehouse, School, Stadium, Park, Warehouse, School, Stadium, Park*. is only two trips on route FOO. If there's a deviation to a location that isn't part of a **known route** eg.  *Warehouse, School, Stadium, Pub, Park*, then that location can be ignored. (ie.  it will still be considered to be route "FOO")

Comment: Can the routes be interrupted? If a route is `Warehouse, School, Pub, Stadium, Pub, Park`, is it still considered `FOO`?

Comment: As long as the vehicle travelled to each location in the order in sequence, the route will be considered completed.  The SQL I posted automatically eliminates rows that aren't explicitly part of the route.  This implies that vehicles may have travelled to other destinations between the route's locations.

Comment: A very interesting question that is, thanks!

Comment: But what if the deviations include some of the locations that constitute the route? For example, should `Warehouse, School, Stadium, School, Stadium, Park` be considered to be the same route as `Warehouse, School, Stadium, Park`?

Comment: Backtracking is not considered part of the same route.  Warehouse, School, Stadium, Park, Warehouse, School, Stadium, Park.  is only two trips on route FOO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @route
        TABLE
        (
        route INT NOT NULL,
        step INT NOT NULL,
        destination INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (route, step)
        )

INSERT
INTO    @route
VALUES
        (1, 1, 1),
        (1, 2, 2),
        (1, 3, 3),
        (1, 4, 4),
        (2, 1, 3),
        (2, 2, 4)

DECLARE @gps
        TABLE
        (
        vehicle INT NOT NULL,
        destination INT NOT NULL,
        ts DATETIME NOT NULL
        )

INSERT
INTO    @gps
VALUES
        (1, 1, '2011-03-30 00:00:00'),
        (1, 2, '2011-03-30 00:00:01'),
        (1, 1, '2011-03-30 00:00:02'),
        (1, 3, '2011-03-30 00:00:03'),
        (1, 3, '2011-03-30 00:00:04'),
        (1, 3, '2011-03-30 00:00:05'),
        (1, 4, '2011-03-30 00:00:06'),
        (1, 1, '2011-03-30 00:00:07'),
        (1, 3, '2011-03-30 00:00:08'),
        (1, 4, '2011-03-30 00:00:09'),
        (1, 1, '2011-03-30 00:00:10'),
        (1, 2, '2011-03-30 00:00:11'),
        (1, 2, '2011-03-30 00:00:12'),
        (1, 3, '2011-03-30 00:00:13'),
        (1, 3, '2011-03-30 00:00:14'),
        (1, 4, '2011-03-30 00:00:15'),
        (1, 3, '2011-03-30 00:00:16'),
        (1, 4, '2011-03-30 00:00:17')
;

WITH    iteration (vehicle, destination, ts, route, edge, step, cnt) AS
        (
        SELECT  vehicle, destination, ts, route, 1, step, cnt
        FROM    (
                SELECT  g.vehicle, r.destination, ts, route, step, cnt,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY route, vehicle ORDER BY ts) rn
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY route) cnt
                        FROM    @route
                        ) r
                JOIN    @gps g
                ON      g.destination = r.destination
                WHERE   r.step = 1
                ) q
        WHERE   rn = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  vehicle, destination, ts, route, edge, step, cnt
        FROM    (
                SELECT  i.vehicle, r.destination, g.ts, i.route, edge + 1 AS edge, r.step, cnt,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.route, g.vehicle ORDER BY g.ts) rn
                FROM    iteration i
                JOIN    @route r
                ON      r.route = i.route
                        AND r.step = (i.step % cnt) + 1
                JOIN    @gps g
                ON      g.vehicle = i.vehicle
                        AND g.destination = r.destination
                        AND g.ts > i.ts
                ) q
        WHERE   rn = 1
        ) 
SELECT  route, vehicle, MAX(edge / cnt)
FROM    iteration
GROUP BY
        route, vehicle
```

Here we have two routes: `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `(3, 4)`

The vehicle made 2 trips on route `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and 4 trips on route `(3, 4)`.

It is important that each route has the steps numbered starting from `1` and without gaps (though if it's not the case, you can easily work around it using an additional `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER()`)

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm posting my attempt at this question for three reasons...

1. To Make Quassnoi's answer look even more elegant
2. Because I spent about two hours on it and I don't want to throw it away
3. On the rare possibility that you're using something earlier than SQL 2005, this might be useful

Here, there are three routes...

```
Foo: Locations 1, 2, 3, 4
Bar: Locations 4, 3, 2, 1
Quicky: Locations 2, 3
```

This query, while long, is giving me the correct results for the test data included:

```
CREATE TABLE #Routes
(
    RouteID INT,
    RouteName VARCHAR(50),
)

CREATE TABLE #RoutePoints
(
    RouteID INT,
    LocationID INT,
    SequenceNumber INT
)

CREATE TABLE #MapLocations
(
    LocationID INT,
    LocationName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #GPSData
(
    VehicleID INT,
    LocationID INT,
    Time DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Routes (RouteID, RouteName) VALUES (1, 'Foo')
INSERT INTO #Routes (RouteID, RouteName) VALUES (2, 'Bar')
INSERT INTO #Routes (RouteID, RouteName) VALUES (3, 'Quicky')

INSERT INTO #MapLocations (LocationID, LocationName) VALUES (1, 'Warehouse')
INSERT INTO #MapLocations (LocationID, LocationName) VALUES (2, 'School')
INSERT INTO #MapLocations (LocationID, LocationName) VALUES (3, 'Stadium')
INSERT INTO #MapLocations (LocationID, LocationName) VALUES (4, 'Park')

INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (1, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (1, 3, 3)
INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (1, 4, 4)

INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (2, 4, 1)
INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (2, 3, 2)
INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (2, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (2, 1, 4)

INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (3, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO #RoutePoints (RouteID, LocationID, SequenceNumber) VALUES (3, 3, 2)

INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 12:17:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 12:18:50.000') 
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 12:19:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 12:20:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 12:21:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 12:22:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 12:23:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 3, '2011-03-26 12:24:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 3, '2011-03-26 12:25:50.000')

INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 18:17:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 18:18:50.000') 
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 18:19:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 18:20:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 18:21:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 18:22:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 18:23:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 3, '2011-03-26 18:24:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 3, '2011-03-26 18:25:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 4, '2011-03-26 18:26:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 4, '2011-03-26 18:27:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 18:28:50.000')

INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 19:17:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 19:18:50.000') 
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 19:19:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 19:20:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 19:21:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 19:22:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 2, '2011-03-26 19:23:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 3, '2011-03-26 19:24:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 3, '2011-03-26 19:25:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 4, '2011-03-26 19:26:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 4, '2011-03-26 19:27:50.000')
INSERT INTO #GPSData (VehicleID, LocationID, Time) VALUES (1, 1, '2011-03-26 19:28:50.000')

CREATE TABLE #GPSRoute
(
    RouteID INT,
    VehicleID INT,
    LocationID INT,
    SequenceNumber INT,
    Time DATETIME,
    StepsInRoute INT
)

INSERT INTO #GPSRoute
(
    RouteID,
    VehicleID,
    LocationID,
    SequenceNumber,
    Time,
    StepsInRoute
)
SELECT
    r.RouteID,
    gps.VehicleID,
    rp.LocationID,
    rp.SequenceNumber,
    gps.Time,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM #RoutePoints
        WHERE RouteID = r.RouteID
    )
FROM
    #Routes r JOIN
    #RoutePoints rp ON r.RouteID = rp.RouteID JOIN
    #GPSData gps ON gps.LocationID = rp.LocationID

SELECT
    r.RouteID,
    r.RouteName, 
    previousRouteStep.VehicleID,
    COUNT(*) / NULLIF(previousRouteStep.StepsInRoute - 1, 0) AS TimesRouteCompleted
FROM
    #Routes r JOIN
    #GPSRoute previousRouteStep ON r.RouteID = previousRouteStep.RouteID JOIN
    #GPSRoute nextRouteStep ON 
        previousRouteStep.RouteID = nextRouteStep.RouteID AND
        previousRouteStep.VehicleID = nextRouteStep.VehicleID AND
        previousRouteStep.SequenceNumber + 1 = nextRouteStep.SequenceNumber AND
        previousRouteStep.Time < nextRouteStep.Time AND

        -- Only include the step if it is followed by the subsequent step.
        nextRouteStep.Time = (
            SELECT MIN(Time)
            FROM #GPSRoute
            WHERE 
                RouteID = nextRouteStep.RouteID AND
                VehicleID = nextRouteStep.VehicleID AND
                sequenceNumber = nextRouteStep.SequenceNumber AND
                Time > previousRouteStep.Time
        ) AND

        -- Only include the step if it is the latest step in the sequence that meets the criteria.
        previousRouteStep.Time = (
            SELECT MAX(Time)
            FROM #GPSRoute
            WHERE
                RouteID = previousRouteStep.RouteID AND
                VehicleID = previousRouteStep.VehicleID AND
                sequenceNumber = previousRouteStep.sequenceNumber AND
                Time < nextRouteStep.Time
        )
WHERE
    -- This step is only valid if every preceding step has been done.
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            #RoutePoints rp LEFT JOIN  
            #GPSRoute gpsr ON           
                gpsr.RouteID = rp.RouteID AND
                gpsr.LocationID = rp.LocationID AND
                gpsr.SequenceNumber = rp.SequenceNumber AND
                gpsr.Time < previousRouteStep.Time  AND
                gpsr.VehicleID = previousRouteStep.VehicleID
        WHERE
            rp.SequenceNumber < previousRouteStep.SequenceNumber AND
            gpsr.RouteID IS NULL AND
            rp.RouteID = previousRouteStep.RouteID
    )
GROUP BY
    r.RouteID,
    r.RouteName,
    previousRouteStep.VehicleID,
    previousRouteStep.StepsInRoute
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to bring back erroneous results. I'll try to narrow it down what causes the problem.

Comment: It seems that it includes trips that have backtracking.  This should not be allowed.  Apologies if it caused confusion.

Comment: Do you have a sample of data that produces the bad results?  With the data here, I get "Foo" traveled twice, "Bar" not fully traveled, and "Quicky" traveled three times.  By backtracking, are we saying that unless the route is traveled in exact sequence, then it isn't considered to have been traveled?

Comment: Yes, ie.  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 is not the same as 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4.  The same goes for 1  -> 2  -> 5  -> 3 -> 4.